# Changing case of words (all upper- and camel-case)

Tags: java, file

So, I'm a complete novice, and I've been having trouble with this for a while. I have to edit this file so that all the vowels and punctuation are gone, and so that the first and last sentence is capitalized, along with the first letter of every word. I've got the first half done, but the second part is giving me trouble.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SMcatcherInTheIO
{
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
File catcher= new File ("C:\\Users\\suvra\\Dropbox\\APCompSci 17-18\\AAA SM EXTRA CREDIT\\RyeCh1.txt"); 
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new FileReader(catcher));
String rye;
while((rye=br.readLine()) !=null)
{     
  for (int i = 0; i < rye.length(); i++) 
  {
  char c = rye.charAt(i);
  if ((c == 'A') || (c == 'a') || (c == 'E') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'I') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'O') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'U') || (c == 'u') 
     || (c == ',') || (c == '.') || (c == '?') || ( c == '!'))
  {
    String front = rye.substring(0, i);
    String back = rye.substring(i + 1);
    rye = front + "" + back;
  }
}
  System.out.println(rye);
}
br.close();
}}
```

Comment: I may be old fashioned, but I think it would be helpful to first figure out the order of the tasks in your desired algorithm, then sketch it out in pseudocode.  You've got a number of distinct units of work that need to be completed.  You've got sentence-level tasks, word-level tasks, and character-level tasks.  I'd think that drawing a flowchart of the results you want at each step will really help you find the algorithm you need, and then it's just a coding thing.  Lastly, after you've got the algorithm for each step, then you can optimize and start combining steps.

Answer (score 0):

Create two String objects :Last and First sentence. Than Loop trought you code and stop at the first point and add value to firstSentence. Do similar for the last sentence just stop at the point-1.  After that:

```
String lastSentence=somethingalreadydoneabove;
    String upperCase=lastSentence.toUpperCase();
```

Hope this would help you. 
DK